# CSS snap scroll: How do I induce the snap scrolling in the middle of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website where I transform the header on scroll. I am now working on implementing CSS snap scrolling to the entire site. Because of this, the scroll-event in javascript obviously doesn't get triggered when the user scrolls down. How might I solve this problem?

I am very new to this so I have not yet tried using any libraries, and would like to avoid that for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Scrollsnapping is nothing that should interfere with the scrollEvent. Please see this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/oliver-barwig/pen/jONmgLG) for a minimal working example. Open the console and scroll, there you'll see the scrollEvent firing.

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => console.log(event));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #7FDBFF ;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can you provide a code example with your specific problem? This will make it easier to help you.